# What does type of error cause XACT_STATE be 1 in the MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, transactions, try-catch

Based on Microsoft document about TRY...CATCH when the XACT_STATE is -1, Transactions are Uncommittable ([TRY...CATCH (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)):

> **Uncommittable Transactions and XACT_STATE**
>
> If an error generated in a TRY block causes the state of the current
>   transaction to be invalidated, the transaction is classified as an
>   uncommittable transaction. **An error that ordinarily ends a transaction
>   outside a TRY block causes a transaction to enter an uncommittable
>   state when the error occurs inside a TRY block.** An uncommittable
>   transaction can only perform read operations or a ROLLBACK
>   TRANSACTION. The transaction cannot execute any Transact-SQL
>   statements that would generate a write operation or a COMMIT
>   TRANSACTION. The XACT_STATE function returns a value of -1 if a
>   transaction has been classified as an uncommittable transaction. When
>   a batch finishes, the Database Engine rolls back any active
>   uncommittable transactions. If no error message was sent when the
>   transaction entered an uncommittable state, when the batch finishes,
>   an error message will be sent to the client application. This
>   indicates that an uncommittable transaction was detected and rolled
>   back.

If I understand it correctly, every error that stops continuity of the TRY block and enters the CATCH block causes the XACT_STATE be -1 (when XACT_ABORT is ON), but in the example C of the mentioned document checks it if is 1:

> .  .  .  END TRY    BEGIN CATCH
>       -- Execute error retrieval routine.
>       EXECUTE usp_GetErrorInfo;
>
> ```
> -- Test XACT_STATE:  
>     -- If 1, the transaction is committable.  
>     -- If -1, the transaction is uncommittable and should   
>     --     be rolled back.  
>     -- XACT_STATE = 0 means that there is no transaction and  
>     --     a commit or rollback operation would generate an error.  
>
> -- Test whether the transaction is uncommittable.  
> IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1  
> BEGIN  
>     PRINT  
>         N'The transaction is in an uncommittable state.' +  
>         'Rolling back transaction.'  
>     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
> END;  
>
> -- Test whether the transaction is committable.  
> IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1  
> BEGIN  
>     PRINT  
>         N'The transaction is committable.' +  
>         'Committing transaction.'  
>     COMMIT TRANSACTION;     
>
> END; END CATCH; GO
> ```

**My question is here:**

Is it wrong example? If not, what kind of errors can cause XACT_STATE be 1 (committable) in the CATCH block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server can tolerate some errors inside a transaction without it having to be marked as uncommittable. For example SELECT 1/0 would cause an error but not force a transaction into an uncommittable state. (Quoted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-transactions.)

In fact, unless XACT_ABORT is on, pretty much any non-fatal error will produce a XACT_STATE of 1 (pk violation, data type conversion, constraint violations, etc). (This taken from https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1109613-1550-1.aspx).

Comment: I think MS document as you mentioned is wrong. Because I use "select 1/0" in a transaction to examine XACT_STATE value in CATCH block by "select XACT_STATE()" command that it returns -1!

Comment: Do you have XactAbort on? That might explain the difference. I've just edited my answer to include this information.

Comment: Yes it is ON. If I don't make it ON, XACT_STATE will be 1 (means committable) but PK Violation etc in fact are not committable!

Comment: I didn't say it was right to turn it off. I'm saying, now you know what kind of errors can cause XACT_STATE to be 1. Which was your question.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. When XACT_ABORT is ON, all errors cause XACT_STATE to -1, even "SELECT 1/0" which it means all T-SQL commands that can commit before error source are not allowed to commit but if it is OFF then error source like "SELECT 1/0" allows all commands before it to commit. Consequently, I think it is a vain work to check XACT_STATE for 1 in CATCH block when XACT_ABORT is ON.